# How much oil can rest in the head valley on a Dodge 3.6L

Tags: oil-leak, durango

Mechanic installed new oil filter housing. Durango 3.6 L. I drove away as the shop was closing, a mile up the road the check engine light came on. I went to the nearest gas station 4 miles away and checked oil levels. I had to add 4 quarts of oil. The work had been done five days prior so the vehicle was just sitting before I picked it up. The mechanic had a tow truck take it back to the shop the next day. No oil on my driveway the next morning prior to towing. He called me and said the housing leaked and the oil was setting on top of the head. 4 quarts I said while my BS meter was going crazy. I drove 5 miles. No smoke no burning odor. Just low 4qts. Did they drain the oil and forget to put oil back in?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds feasible, but realistically there's no way to definitively say it happened.

Comment: I disagree: 4 quarts of oil with no trace on the motor or on the ground or on the exhaust manifolds (creating smoke) is not feasible. Your BS meter was correct.

Comment: Does you car have an oil pressure gauge or oil pressure warning light.  I am surprised it didn’t come on immediately if you had to add a gallon on oil.  How much oil does the engine take?